# How to get file metadata by REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, pnp

I have a video file named `simpleVideo2 (360p).mp4` in folder `Video Assets`(It's document library), and I want to know if it's possible to fetch file metadata through the REST API to get the video's duration?

I tried searching for relevant information in `PnP.js`, but I couldn't find any results regarding `CAMLQuery`. As a result, I couldn't understand the examples provided in [PnP.js](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/items/#filter-using-metadata-fields)

If possible, I would also like to retrieve the `thumbnail` of the video.

[image: Video duration property in spfx-list]

Comment: Do you want to get video's duration dynamically? or do you have custom column in document library for video duration where you set video duration manually?

Comment: I have a document library where I store videos, and I want to display their durations on my page (a list). I noticed that the file summary information in SPFx list has this property, so I'm wondering if it's possible to retrieve it through REST API or any other means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file information panel in your picture uses the SharePoint REST api v2.1, which returns unformatted metadata on video files like in the following Postman screenshot.

[image]

Unfortunately the documentation on using the v2.1 REST api is pretty minimal, however the endpoints are basically the same as for the Microsoft Graph api and the Drive/DriveItem endpoints.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/sharepoint-rest-graph

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I haven't used the `Graph API` before, and there's so much to learn about SPFx. Besides the Microsoft documentation and PnP community, do you have any other recommended learning websites? Specifically, related to the knowledge that might be involved in my question.

Comment: Nothing specific for learning, but there is a lot to know. Web searching helps a lot, as does being proficient with tools like the browser dev tools, Postman, Fiddler etc, as sometimes you need to figure things out for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using PnP.js try this:

```
// file is an IFile and supports all the file operations
const file = await sp.web.getFileByServerRelativePath(url);
const props = await file.listItemAllFields
          .select("*,listItemAllFields")
          .expand("listItemAllFields")
          .get();
```